# “No new release found” when upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 LTS?

Tags: server, upgrade, proxy, firewall, release-management

I'm trying to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 LTS. When I go to do-release-upgrade, though, I get a message "no new release found."

I've tried editing (or not editing) /update-manager/release-upgrades; I've tried do-release-upgrade -d; I've tried everything I could find on the internet.

One twist to this is that the server I'm trying to upgrade is behind a local mirror; that is, instead of downloading from ubuntu directly, it's downloading from this local mirror; the server is behind a firewall of sorts. Are there special servers that need to be in sources.list for do-release-upgrade? I'm at a loss.

Comment: Ensure your system is fully upgraded (`sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` not just *upgrade*) before you try to *bump* releases. Also as you mention mirrors, check on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors to ensure you mirror isn't *Last update unknown* (meaning it was far enough back to exceed counter).

Comment: Thanks. I tried the full-upgrade (as well as dist-upgrade earlier) but unfortunately it didn't work. The mirror I'm using is a private mirror, in the sense that it's for a local network for machines isolated from the global network (these machines have no ability to access the outside internet directly). So I don't see it listed in lists of mirrors like that one. The next step I'm considering is adding the newer releases to the sources.list but I'm worried that could cause lots of problems.

Comment: Your latest revision looks like an answer. I've rolled back that edit. Consider posting that edit as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had to edit the file /etc/update-manager/meta-release to point to the location on the local mirror where the meta-release file is located. That is, rather than point to the URL http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release, I edited /etc/update-manager/meta-release to point to the URL of the local mirror. do-release-upgrade uses /etc/update-manager/meta-release to determine the location of the meta-release file, which it then uses to determine whether a new release is available.

Comment: Hmm this won't work for me since I don't have a local mirror :-(

Answer (score 1):

https://0x00sec.org/t/ubuntu-upgrading-from-14-04-to-16-04-what-to-do-if-do-release-upgrade-does-not-work/836

```
cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
# Default behavior for the release upgrader.

[DEFAULT]
# ...
Prompt=lts
```

The prompt should be lts or default, and not never